# Android Studio - Only one build.gradle in the projetct folder

Tags: java, facebook, android-studio

So I started working on my first app in Andorid Studio and I was hoping to implement a login feature that uses Facebook. When watching tutorials, I noticed that they have two build.gradle, one is the project and the other is the module.

My project only has one build.gradle and I'm unsure why.

[Screenshot of only one build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNa98.png)

I added a screenshot to visually show you what I mean. If anyone can explain to me where I went wrong, that would be appreciated. Thank you so much and Happy holidays :)

Somron Touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the view of the file structure in Android Studio by selecting "Android" from the drop down in the top left corner. [See this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5a9k.png)
Hope this helps!